# Samsung smart tv browser in fullscreen mode

Tags: browser, samsung-smart-tv

Can I start browser in fullscreen mode on Samsung Smart TV (LED TV series 5) ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is how to do it on the TV Samsung UE32H4510 :

- In the browser click in the upper right corner on the gear icon
- Go to "Browser Settings"
- Go to the "General" sub-menu
- And then you have an option called "Hide menu" ("Masquer menu" in French) that you need to enable
- Finally you need to restart the browser application to have the menu hidden

Comment: It is named differenty in the recent TV firmware, but there is such a setting on that tab an it works the expected way.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. I have requested this feature from Samsung, but they have not answered me. Top navigation will be always visible in Samsung TV's.

Comment: Thanks, so the solution for my problem was to buy third party device (like some android device), with a brower that can do that, and connect it to TV.

Comment: Yes you can, check the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

New information for this old question.

On a 65" Samsung TV purchase in the U.S.A.

1. Open the WebBrowser
2. Navigate to the streaming event you want to watch.

Only takes 20 seconds to go full screen.

Using the remote's simple navigation ring and center Ok button:

3. Click the 'Hamburger' button upper right
4. Click Settings
5. Under the top option 'Hide Tabs and Menu Bar' click "Use"
6. Click on the tab just left (your streaming event)
7. Click on the 'Refresh' icon (the over under circle icon just left of the bookmark star)
8. Wait 15 seconds and BOOYA! Joy! Your stream is full screen.  Get the popcorn,  a drink and enjoy.

Later) Force the browser's Tabs and Menu to re-appear buy using the remote in the same way to simply navigate to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do on my **Samsung Freestyle LSP3** with preinstalled **Tizen** OS:

1. From the Main Menu (Home button), go to the **Internet App** which opens in the web browser.
2. On the top bar next to the close button (`x`, should be on the right) there is the **Internet Menu**, click it and click **Settings**.
3. In the **General** section of the Settings there is an option called *"Hide Tabs and Toolbar automatically"*, set this to `Use`.

Done. Unless you interact with tabs or the toolbar it will quickly hide automatically and give you a full screen view.

---

Hm. It took me some time to find that out by myself and answers I found on the Internet were not useful at all. In part it was my fault. As a desktop user who has not owned a TV for a very long time I expected a full screen option in a web browser to be named as such and easily accessible.

How did I find this? I was looking into the Workspace functionality and was brought to a website where the browser hid the toolbar automatically. That was when I thought »Okay, so it is possible?«. And then I found the option in the settings which I overlooked until this point. Yep, seems like the browser uses different profiles depending on if it is started by a user or another app.